# Getting textbox value in javascript code after onchange

Tags: javascript, asp.net

On my page, I'm using textbox with calendar extender to get the date value.
I've added `onchange="ValidateStartDate();"` to the textbox.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxStartDate" runat="server"  ForeColor="Red"    
     onchange="ValidateRsmStartDate();"> 
     </asp:TextBox>               

<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtenderStartDate" 
  TargetControlID="TextBoxStartDate"
  BehaviorID="ceStartDate"  
  PopupButtonID="CalendarExtenderStartDatePopup"                                                                     
  Format="MM/dd/yyyy" runat="server">
  </asp:CalendarExtender>

<img class="Spacer" id="CalendarExtenderStartDatePopup" src="Images/Calendar.png"                                                                                
   alt="Start Date" />
```

My javascript function:

```
function ValidateStartDate() {
   var txtDate = document.getElementById('<%=TextBoxStartDate.ClientID  %>');
   alert(txtDate.innerHTML);
}
```

But on `alert()`, I get no value at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Textbox does `not` have `innerHTML`, you need to use `value`

Change

```
alert(txtDate.innerHTML);
```

To

```
alert(txtDate.value);
```

Comment: You are welcome, No worries some times we forget simple things.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily integrate it from jquery. Just write below line in your function.

```
alert($("#<%=TextBoxStartDate.ClientID  %>").val());
```

Or

Replace your code from `alert(txtDate.innerHTML);` to `alert(txtDate.value);`

Answer (score 0):

**Using jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    $('<%=TextBoxStartDate.ClientID%>').on("change", function(){
     alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```